# Rails Rumble - Can I See the Code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, open-source

I've came across a code of couple projects from the *Rails Rumble 2010* hosted on Github. But this is just a tiny percent of total amount of projects.

Is it possible to have a read-only copy of git repositories from all(or best) projects from Rails Rumble 2010?

P.S. I really tried to find an answer on official website

Answer (score 2):

It's up to individual teams whether or not they open up their code.

On the [Contest Rules](http://blog.railsrumble.com/rules) page under section 8, Ownership and Open Source:

> Hey, we’re just running a competition here. What you do with your source once the competition is over is up to you. We encourage participants to open source the codebase of their applications for the benefit of the community. However, if you choose not to open source your application, well that’s up to you.